# Pressure required for gas to flow through an orifice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Imagine I have an upside-down cone, which is filled with a gas - let's say it is air. At the bottom of this cone is an extremely small hole (a few microns in diameter). How do I go about calculating how much pressure is required for the gas to flow through this extremely small hole. In particular, I am interested in finding the threshold pressure, above which the air would flow through the gap and below which the air would not flow through the gap.

Comment: What is upside down cone? Bottom narrow or wide?

Comment: There is no non-zero pressure where the flow will be zero. You have a case of [*flow through an orifice*](http://www.mcnallyinstitute.com/13-html/13-12.htm).

Answer (score -1):

A few micrometres is general gap between cotton shirt threads. Even as slight as 0.0000001Pa pressure difference should be enough for gas to pass, with atomic size being in nanometers.

If cone had water instead of air, surface tension would have prevented it. But because you fill cone with air, vanderwall forces here are very  weak. So, surface tension is weakest or almost nil here.

The probability of gas particles to pass through holes although would reduce and more of particles would strike mesh rather than passing holes.

Comment: Surface tension is only present when there are 2 phases involved.  This is a single phase situation.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Bhai sahab, Is cone made of air???

Comment: the fluid that is flowing is single phase, and the cone is rigid.  So, in your best judgment, how does surface tension come into this problem.  Please provide your aerodynamic differential  equations that include surface tension.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Surface tension tends to keep liquid drop spherical. There is an angle of contact between water and surface which causes causes bulging of liquid, disturbing surface tension. The phenomenon is applied to explain why water does not flow out of an inverted glass when covered at mouth with cloth.

Comment: The only fluid in this problem is air.  What have you got to say about that?  Where is your interface with another fluid?

Comment: @ChesterMiller My other interface is cone itself. The boundary of cone serves for other surface. The interface is not necessary b/w liquid-liquid. It may be solid-gas, liquid-gas, solid-liquid etc.

Comment: If you want to think this, fine.  I have yet to see your fluid dynamic  equation(s)  that include the effect of your concept of  surface tension (at a rigid solid-gas interface) on the air flow.  If you can't produce those equations for this particular problem, it is very difficult to see how you can be taken seriously.  As a person with over 50 years of experience in fluid mechanics (including actual practical problems involving surface tension in industry), I would find your analysis (i.e., your set of equations applied to this particular problem) very interesting.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Last year I went to a quiz competition in MK school here in my locality. In one of experimental round they took a glass of water and a plastic sieve. The water easily flow through seive. Then,  they covered mouth of glass with sieve and inverted it suddenly. As to surprise no water fell out of it. We are asked why? I replied first because of pressure difference (I knew about same trick with cardboard where pressure difference is cause) but it was wrong. Then, instinctly I said because of surface tension. It was correct. They expanded answer to explain how cohesive force between

Comment: water molecules lead to surface tension and hence water does not fell out.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Similarly if cone had water instead of air, surface tension would have prevented it. But because OP fills cone with air, vanderwall forces here are very  weak. So, surface tension is weakest or almost nil here.

Comment: @ChesterMiller My book gives no equations for this. This is my Anubhav(experience) of 2 years.

Comment: I find your MK school quiz competition experience very amusing, but, as you said, the surface tension effect is negligible in the OP's problem:  " But because OP fills cone with air, vanderwall forces here are very weak. So, surface tension is weakest or almost nil here."  In your quiz question, there were three phases present, and, most importantly, an interface between the air and the water.  In the present situation, there is only air and solid.  I think that we are finally in agreement.

Comment: @ChesterMiller If not upvote, removal of downvote expected.

Comment: If you're unhappy with your downvote, just delete your answer (and you will get your reputation points back).

Comment: From your description, any positive pressure in the cone over the pressure outside the cone will cause  flow. If pressure is equal on each side of the hole, there will be no flow. What are you trying to determine?

Comment: @GerardDeSantis Thanks for pointing. I am saying any non zero pressure difference will result in air flow.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Its not like that. Deleted answers are counted for badges.